# why toran generate package json with domain : examle.org?

Tags: toran-proxy

I do as toran proxy document step by step, but i occur a problem

I have configure toran_host and toran_prot in parameters.yml, but generated package josn remain using the the domain

example.org

[image]

Package.json
 [image]
I try to find issue source, but the application is too complex for me.

this is my parameters.yml:

```
parameters:
    # this secret should be changed to something unique and random if possible
    secret:         ThisTokenIsNotSoSecret-Change-It

    # http or https depending on your hosting setup
    toran_scheme:   http

    # in case you use non-standard ports you can update them here
    toran_http_port: 91
    toran_https_port: 443

    # the hostname toran is hosted at
    toran_host: 121.199.35.34:91

    # e.g. /foo if toran is hosted in a sub-directory, or leave it empty if it is on its own domain, no trailing slash!
    toran_base_url:
```

Answer (score 0):

but have you tried clearing the cache? Delete 
everything in ·app/cache/· and try again, because the parameters need to 
be set correctly before the cache is created otherwise it is not rebuilt.

this answer come from Jordi's email to me, he is a author of toran, thank for nice and hard work .

Answer (score 0):

You have to modify your config file at `app/config/parameters.yml`:

```
# the hostname toran is hosted at
toran_host:     example.org
```

Then delete the production cache at `app/cache/prod`, and finally run the cron job again `php bin/cron -v`

For further instructions follow official installation documentation here: https://toranproxy.com/download